# SOAPUI client Testing webService

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, soapui

I am using SoapUI to test the web service. In that I can able to format one request and get the response back.

now My requirement is I need to prepare a file(not sure about the format) and I have to send 50 to 100 different requests at a time from the soapUI client and get the response back.

Colud any one help me out in this?

Comment: http://blog.imaginea.com/automating-soap-api-tests-with-soap-ui/

Answer (score 0):

You can use datasource to load the input for which you want to get back response and then loop it using datasource loop step

More info : http://www.soapui.org/Data-Driven-Testing/datasources.html

Not sure if this what you are looking for.